# Ajax Post Submit Function Submits Twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I've tried many of the other solutions to this problem on SO, and elsewhere, but I can't seem to prevent my form from submitting twice. Here is the code that I'm currently having this issue with:

**jQuery Code**

```
$(function() {
  var additemtoform = $('#additemform');
  var handleData = function(responseData) {
    if ($(responseData).find('#repitems').length) {
      var replacement = $('<div />').html(responseData).find('#repitems').html();
      $('#test').html(replacement);
    } else {
      additemtoform.submit();
    }
  };

  $("#additemform .addbtn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'WebCatPageServer.exe',
      dataType: 'html',
      cache: false,
      data: additemtoform.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {},
      success: function(data) {
        handleData(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

If I remove the submit in the callback, then the form doesn't submit at all. So, what am I missing?

Thanks!

**Update**
Note that this code is update from the original per Habbe's suggestion below. The same issue with the double submit persists, however.

**HTML Code (Generated)**

```
  <form name="AddItem" id="additemform" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe">
    <input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Add_Item" />
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?PROD_FULL&ProdInfo=00012000551">BRW2394746301</a></td>
                    <td>239-47463-01</td>
                    <td>Gas Valve Complete, Icon Natural Gas</td>
                    <td> $207.32</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Q1" tabindex="1" class="qtyfield" type="text" size="1" value="0" onblur="clickrecall(this,'0')" onfocus="Q1.select()" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="P1" type="hidden" value="BRW2394746301" />
                        <input name="M1" type="hidden" value="239-47463-01" />
                        <input name="D1" type="hidden" value="Gas Valve Complete, Icon Natural Gas" />
                        <button type="button" class="button lightgray smallrounded addbtn" value="Add">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?PROD_FULL&ProdInfo=00012000552">BRW2394746501</a></td>

                    <td>239-47465-01</td>
                    <td>Gas Valve Complete , Icon Propane</td>
                    <td> $272.58</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Q2" tabindex="2" class="qtyfield" type="text" size="1" value="0" onblur="clickrecall(this,'0')" onfocus="Q2.select()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="P2" type="hidden" value="BRW2394746501" />
                        <input name="M2" type="hidden" value="239-47465-01" />
                        <input name="D2" type="hidden" value="Gas Valve Complete , Icon Propane" />
                        <button type="button" class="button lightgray smallrounded addbtn" value="Add">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?PROD_FULL&ProdInfo=00012000553" style="text-decoration:underline;">BRW2334784505</a></td>
                    <td>233-47845-05</td>
                    <td>Pilot Assembly, Icon Natural Gas</td>
                    <td>  $32.58</td>
                    <td>Available</td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="Q3" tabindex="3" class="qtyfield" type="text" size="1" value="0" onblur="clickrecall(this,'0')" onfocus="Q3.select()" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="P3" type="hidden" value="BRW2334784505" />
                        <input name="M3" type="hidden" value="233-47845-05" />
                        <input name="D3" type="hidden" value="Pilot Assembly, Icon Natural Gas" />
                        <button type="button" class="button lightgray smallrounded addbtn" value="Add">Add</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**Solution - Final Code**

As it turns out, I was overthinking this. The form was submitting via ajax on the initial submit. The form was submitted again in the callback. Since an item was added to the cart on the initial submit, I simply loaded the cart page in the callback.

```
$(function() {
var additemtoform = $('#additemform');

// Reset Qty to 0 on Page Load
$('#additemform .inputqty').val('0');

//Ajax CallBack
var handleData = function(responseData) {
if ($(responseData).find('#repitems').length) {
var replacement = $('<div />').html(responseData).find('#repitems').html();
$(replacement).appendTo('body').modal();
} else {
location.href =  "WebCatPageServer.exe?Cart";
}
};

$("#additemform .addbtn").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();


// If qty is 0, set value to 1
if($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').val() === '0'){
$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').val('1');
}
else {
}


// Post Form
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'WebCatPageServer.exe',
dataType: 'html',
cache: false,
data: additemtoform.serialize(),
beforeSend: function() {},
success: function(data) {
handleData(data);
},
error: function() {
alert('error');
}
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: improve your code formating.

Comment: Does that look better?

Comment: what type of button is `addbtn`? Is it a `submit` or a `type="button"`?

Comment: It's a type="button"

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: I've updated above to include the generated HTML code for the form.

Answer (score 1):

NB! ensure that the binding occurs just once and that you don't have multiple submit elements in your form.

You could try to include the event.stopPropagation call.  I dont see how this could effect anything, but perhaps worth a shot.

```js
$(function() {
  var additemtoform = $('#additemform');
  var handleData = function(responseData) {
    if ($(responseData).find('#repitems').length) {
      var replacement = $('<div />').html(responseData).find('#repitems').html();
      $('#test').html(replacement);
    } else {
      additemtoform.submit();
    }
  };

  $("#additemform .addbtn").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'WebCatPageServer.exe',
      dataType: 'html',
      cache: false,
      data: additemtoform.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {},
      success: function(data) {
        handleData(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Habbe, thanks. I don't have any additional submit elements in the form. This code is cleaner, but still appears to submit the form twice.

Comment: is the addbtn a submit element? If so, then mahaps the submit method will cause the click event to refire.

Comment: Habbe, the addbtn is a button type="button".

Comment: Do you have any submit elements in the form at all?  if not i think Firefox will treat button elements as submits. Try moving the button outside the form.

Comment: I don't have any submit elements in the form at all. I didn't think moving the button outside of the form would work, but tried it for kicks and confirmed that it doesn't work. I need to hit the sack, but will pick this up in the morning. I welcome any additional thoughts, and thanks for your help.

Comment: I would set a breakpoint before the submit call and look at the stack trace.  And if the breakpoint is only hit once the error lays in the actual submit method.  It could help if you show us the html.

Comment: I've updated above to include the generated HTML code for the form.

Answer (score 0):

On the third line, the function(e) is open telling function handleData(responseData) to run oy omitting the closing }. Then in the ajax you tell function handleData(responseData) to run again.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I think Habbe illustrated the fix for the error you pointed out. It's still double-submitting, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(function() {
    var additemtoform = $('#additemform');
    $("#additemform .addbtn").off().on("click", function(e) {
    ///your code


});
```

Comment: Thanks, Amit_183. The issue persists, however.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be, because you are calling submit form action twice. Once in the form tag, and secondly in jquery. Try removing one and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

During first time ajax call, the form is not submitted. Just passes the call and receives response length 0 or null. So the else part demands form submission again. So try to submit the form before first call and make sure form submit target is self().

Good Luck!

Comment: I removed your references to your website from the four answers you have given on SO so far. Please refrain from including a link to your personal sites when those have nothing to do with the context of the question – this is considered *spam* on SO. Use your profile to place such references, so that people interested in that kind of information can go there to get it.